# Draw confidence interval in R

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Can you explain me how, with R code, we draw coverage graph for the CI?
For example, we have 40 samples (each one of size 20) and we have calculated the CI for each one of the 40. Our mission right now is to draw something like that:

[image: Coverage Graph in R]

Where each line is for vector of 20 samples, and the Y axis is for the actual interval.

Note: I have the "pivot" of each interval (the middle point).

Thanks!

Comment: Your display of CIs is similar to one in Suess (2010), but that one is for binomial data, and the R code to make it is not shown. // Your display shows 16 covering CIs out of 20, which is an 'unlucky' result if the intended confidence level is 95%.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have 40 samples and only show 20. From the information given, it
is not possible to know from which population distribution you are sampling
[I used $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 0, \sigma=15)$] or what confidence level you
are using [I used 95%]. Also, I used $m =40$ samples of size $n = 20.$

I used standard t confidence intervals of the form
$$ \bar X \pm t^* S/\sqrt{n},$$
where $t^* = 2.093$ cuts 2.5% from the upper tail of Student's t distribution
with $\nu = 20 - 1 = 19$ degrees of freedom. So the center of each interval
is the sample mean. (You may be mis-using the term 'pivot'.)

On average, there will be 2 confidence intervals
out of 40 that do not cover. For the seed chosen, there happen to be 38 CIs that
cover and two that don't. (If you want a variety of plots, delete the `set.seed`
statement before you make subsequent runs of the program.)

You can adjust constants on the second line of the R code shown below the figure to get
exactly what you want. (The R code is entirely from the base of R,
with no special libraries required.)

[image]

```
set.seed(1776)
m = 40;  n = 20;  mu = 0;  sigma = 15;  conf.level = .95
x = rnorm(m*n, mu, sigma)
MAT = matrix(x, nrow=m)  # m x n matrix: each row a sample of size n
x.bar = rowMeans(MAT);  s = apply(MAT, 1, sd)

t.crit = qt(1-(1-conf.level)/2, n-1)
LCL = x.bar - t.crit*s/sqrt(n);  UCL = x.bar + t.crit*s/sqrt(n)
cover = LCL < mu & UCL > mu
HI = max(UCL); LO = min(LCL)  # to set dimensions of the plot

plot(c(0,m+1), c(HI, LO), col="white", ylab="", xlab="Sample", main="", xaxs="i")
  abline(h=mu, col="green2")
  for(i in 1:m) {bar="blue"; if (cover[i]==F) {bar="red"}
    lines(c(i,i), c(UCL[i], LCL[i]), col=bar, lwd=2) }
```

.

```
i = 1:40; cbind(i, LCL, UCL, cover)
       i         LCL        UCL cover
 [1,]  1 -10.7907965  5.3863254     1
 [2,]  2  -5.5686896  6.8660868     1
 [3,]  3  -9.0946722  3.9352009     1
 [4,]  4  -3.0539188  9.8247816     1
...
[10,] 10  -9.0793201  3.1892928     1
[11,] 11  -5.5498471  9.8125370     1
[12,] 12  -4.3934771  4.6644040     1
[13,] 13   0.7405062 12.8408320     0   # Doesn't cover 0
[14,] 14  -8.6025527  6.0888690     1
[15,] 15  -9.2913948  8.3837346     1
[16,] 16 -12.5804007  3.4733748     1
[17,] 17  -9.9732150  2.4025221     1
[18,] 18  -9.0158737  6.1480452     1
[19,] 19  -9.4274926  8.9666786     1
...
[30,] 30  -8.8345204  8.4811912     1
[31,] 31  -8.5916045  3.1271369     1
[32,] 32  -6.7154571  6.0728731     1
[33,] 33  -8.5203468  5.4368537     1
[34,] 34 -12.0104057 -0.6229541     0   # Doesn't cover 0
[35,] 35  -0.6030757 13.2032218     1
[36,] 36  -7.0561399  5.3908935     1
[37,] 37  -5.5087385  8.1079198     1
[38,] 38  -1.6004350  9.5415809     1
[39,] 39  -6.2662541  7.9475938     1
[40,] 40  -0.4373327 14.7683446     1
```